# Parsing email messages

Tags: email, parsing, email-client

I want to extract the body of some email messages. Trouble is the body sometimes contains quoted text which seems to come in different formats. Am I right to think there is no standard when it comes to quoting text in emails?

Anyway, any tips on extracting just the message without other things like quoted text, the original sender, the chain of receivers etc.?

Comment: Nope, there are no standards, just a dozen different conventions piled up over the years. You can make a heuristic, but it will be horribly complicated and get it wrong often. Perhaps you should invent your own quoting convention; at least you'll know it works within your system ;)